# Embedding a Word Document Form into HTML

Tags: html, forms, embed

I have a Word document form that can be filled out by the user, meant for data collection, which can be seen here (http://comm.soc.northwestern.edu/bilingualism-psycholinguistics/leapq/). What I want to do is have it available on a website so that when the form is completed, it can be submitted with the information posted to a PHP page which can then analyze the data. To my knowledge, I can't embed the document directly into an HTML page; is there some way I can convert this document into an HTML form? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `File` > `Save As` > `Other formats` > `Web Page (*.htm, *.html)`?

Comment: Just tried that. The problem is that the resulting web page no longer has the input fields that the Word document did.